# Integrate/link Tomcat web service (JSP) with user login into/with website

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, jsp, tomcat

In our company we use a software for human resource management where employee data can be maintained, documents can be viewed and leave requests and sick leave etc. can be submitted. The employee must log in with his/her personnel number and a password to gain access.

The provider of the software has provided us with a web module for this purpose, but its design cannot really be adapted (CSS options are limited to font colours, font sizes, etc.). In particular, it lacks a responsive layout, which makes it much more difficult to use on smartphones, which is how it is mostly used.

I am now considering whether it is somehow possible to integrate this web module into our website. I am not interested in frames, as these would not solve the problem. Rather, I was thinking of solving this via links, if that is at all possible. The web module runs on Apache Tomcat and the pages are .jsp files.

For example: Employee presses the "Documents" button on our website and it is treated as if he/she had clicked on "Documents" in the web module; he/she fills out a form field on our website and it is treated as if he/she had filled it out in the web module, etc.

Direct access to the database is not possible, so I don't even know if what I have in mind can be realised at all.

To be honest, I haven't tried anything yet because I have no idea at all how to get started here - if you can get started at all.

I hope I have been able to convey the facts reasonably well. Maybe someone has an idea how to approach this.

Comment: Assuming you are asking x from that web module and you get y, that sounds pretty like APIs. Ideally that web module they gave you should expose its functionalities as APIs so you can adapt your application and call them directly.